# How to use Switch in C#

Tags: c#

I have some possibilities to execute a specific command according to the choice from the combo box. I used the if statement, but I found that almost the same code was repeated in more than one case.
My question is: the question is there a short way to do this like using switch statement? This is the code I used for each button:

````
        {
            if (cmbTrans.Text == "bad")
            {
                string istrue = "true";
                bool mybool = Convert.ToBoolean(istrue);
                trans.ADD_NEW_TRANS(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), dtTransDate.Value, txtVibNO.Text, cmbSenderSite.Text, cmbRecievedSite.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkHours.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbTrans.SelectedValue), Program.userInfo.UserName);
                vib.UPDATE_TRANS_ISOFF(txtVibNO.Text, mybool);

                MessageBox.Show("done", "done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                btnSave.Enabled = false;
            if (cmbTrans.Text == "good")
            {
                string istrue = "false";
                bool mybool = Convert.ToBoolean(istrue);
                trans.ADD_NEW_TRANS(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), dtTransDate.Value, txtVibNO.Text, cmbSenderSite.Text, cmbRecievedSite.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkHours.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbTrans.SelectedValue), Program.userInfo.UserName);
                vib.UPDATE_TRANS_ISOFF(txtVibNO.Text, mybool);

                MessageBox.Show("done", "done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                btnSave.Enabled = false;

               
            }

   if (cmbTrans.Text == "Send")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbRecievedSite.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSenderSite.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please specify the sender and the receiver", "!attention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    return;
                }

                string istrue = "true";
                bool mybool = Convert.ToBoolean(istrue);
                trans.ADD_NEW_TRANS(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), dtTransDate.Value, txtVibNO.Text, cmbSenderSite.Text, cmbRecievedSite.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkHours.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbTrans.SelectedValue), Program.userInfo.UserName);
                vib.UPDATE_TRANS_ISOFF(txtVibNO.Text, mybool);

                MessageBox.Show("done", "done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                btnSave.Enabled = false;

            }
                          if (cmbTrans.Text == "Receive")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbRecievedSite.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSenderSite.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please specify the sender and the receiver", "!attention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    return;
                }

                string istrue = "true";
                bool mybool = Convert.ToBoolean(istrue);
                trans.ADD_NEW_TRANS(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), dtTransDate.Value, txtVibNO.Text, cmbSenderSite.Text, cmbRecievedSite.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkHours.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbTrans.SelectedValue), Program.userInfo.UserName);
                vib.UPDATE_TRANS_ISOFF(txtVibNO.Text, mybool);

                MessageBox.Show("done", "done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                btnSave.Enabled = false;

               
            }
  
            }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an function and call that function.

```
public void Foo()
{
                string istrue = "true";
                bool mybool = Convert.ToBoolean(istrue);
                trans.ADD_NEW_TRANS(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), dtTransDate.Value, txtVibNO.Text, cmbSenderSite.Text, cmbRecievedSite.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkHours.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbTrans.SelectedValue), Program.userInfo.UserName);
                vib.UPDATE_TRANS_ISOFF(txtVibNO.Text, mybool);

                MessageBox.Show("done", "done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                btnSave.Enabled = false;
}
```

And you can use switch like this

```
        switch (cmbTrans.Text)
        {
            case "Good": //this is mean if(cmbTrans.Text == "Good")
                {
                    Foo();
                    //code
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
```